# Update from Spring-security-3 to Spring-security-4 caused XML error

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-security

After updating to Spring security 4 my rest-security.xml has an error in it

```
Attribute 'access-denied-page' is not allowed to appear in element 'security:http'
```

Currently my rest-security.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <security:http pattern="/rest/**" auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="response403EntryPoint"/>

    <security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"
        access-denied-page="/#/not-authorized">

        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="jsonAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    </security:http>

    <bean id="customAuthenticationManager" class="com.nortal.security.CustomAuthenticationManager" p:username="admin"
        p:password="admin" />

    <bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        p:defaultFailureUrl="/rest/security/login-failed" />

    <bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        p:defaultTargetUrl="/rest/security/check" />

    <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        p:loginFormUrl="/#/login" />

    <bean id="response403EntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/>

    <bean id="jsonAuthenticationProcessingFilter" class="com.nortal.security.JsonAuthenticationProcessingFilter"
        p:authenticationManager-ref="customAuthenticationManager" p:authenticationFailureHandler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        p:authenticationSuccessHandler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

    <security:authentication-manager />
</beans>
```

And this element is causing the error:

```
<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"
        access-denied-page="/#/not-authorized">
```

Attribute `access-denied-page` is not allowed. How should I change my `rest-security.xml` file to make it compatible with Spring security 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"
        access-denied-page="/#/not-authorized">

        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="jsonAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
</security:http>
```

replace it with

```
<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/#/not-authorized"/>
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="jsonAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
</security:http>
```

In spring security 4 **acces-denied-page** has been replaced with **access-denied-handler**

Documentation [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-deprecations-config-http-adp)